# opendirectoryd consumes 40% of CPU

Tags: macos, osx-lion, process, cpu-usage

I have a MacBook Pro with Lion 10.7.2, 2.26 GHz CPU and 2GB DDR3 RAM.

If I call

```
top -o cpu
```

the `/usr/libexec/opendirectoryd` process consumes more than 40% of CPU.

```
$ ps aux | grep opend                                                                       
root 27834 40,4 0,3 2472048 5780 ?? Rs 6:36PM 167:19.66 /usr/libexec/opendirectoryd
```

[image]

Comment: @slhck  `/usr/libexec/opendirectoryd`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is related to the dead symlinks in Dropbox. Find them using:

```
find ~/Dropbox -type l -printf "%Y %p\n" | grep "^N"
```

The solution is: Remove the dead symlinks. If `find` doesn't have the `printf` option, use:

```
find -L ~/Dropbox -type l
```

#### References

[To find dead symlinks](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=15630&replies=13#post-97728)

Comment: Wonder how you got the first solution to work with the BSD `find` in OS X. You have to at least install GNU `findutils` for getting the `printf` option.

Comment: I have installed findutils

    find --version                                              13:17
    find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2

Comment: Okay, well it doesn't ship with OS X so that command you used wouldn't have worked.

Comment: BSD version of the find command that list broken symlinks:  ```find '~/Dropbox' -type l -print0 | xargs -0 file   | grep broken```

Comment: finding broken links with test should work everywhere: `find ~/Dropbox -type l ! -exec test -e {} \; -print`. Then if you like the looks of the output you can add `-delete` to remove them.

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned by @juanpablo, this may be caused by symlinks.

Apparently, if a symlink points to `/home`, autofs or automountd fire and take a lot of CPU to figure out that the place indeed doesn't exist.

Take a look at `/etc/auto_home` and `/etc/autofs.conf`.

To see if you're being hit by this particular problem, set

```
AUTOMOUNTD_VERBOSE=TRUE
```

option in `autofs.conf`, restart automountd

```
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.automountd
```

and review the syslog.log (you may use application: Console). You're affected by this problem if you see something like that:

```
May 20 17:53:43 xxx automountd[31709]: od_search failed
```

To workaround, edit the file `/etc/auto_master` and remove (or hash out `#`) the line starting with `/home`. Then run:

```
sudo automount -vc
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem as well, and it was related to Dropbox - I had some dead links pointing to `/home` in my Dropbox folder (leftover backups from previous systems) that were causing this behavior. Disabling `/home` in auto_home fixed it.

Comment: Didn't see anything in the logs, but commenting out /home in the automounter config still worked... But why on earth would a supposedly professional OS go bananas just because of some random symlink?

Answer (score 1):

For me what really solved it was unplugging ethernet cable from my iMac. Crazy as it sounds :) I was being attacked from outside, bruteforce on my sshd. The router I have (from UPC, Cisco EPC3925) by default forwards all the traffic from outside to the single ethernet port it has. By unplugging the cable the attack stopped as the iMac was left on WiFi only.

Apparently sshd is using opendirectoryd and that's why this was happening.